# How can I define ShapeBuilder for SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

As we know we have a very useful wrapper called @ViewBuilder for view but I am missing same wrapper for Shape protocol, Since there is no wrapper for this available, I am looking to try build one for learning porous.

Here is working code for view and looking to build the wrapper for Shape:

```
@ViewBuilder func testForView(value: Bool) -> some View {
    if value {
         Text("Hello")
    }
    else {
         Button("world!") {}
    }
}

// The Goal:
@ShapeBuilder func testForShape(value: Bool) -> some Shape {
    if value {
         Circle()
    }
    else {
         Rectangle()
    }
}
```

I have experience working with wrappers or even defining a custom wrapper, but all my attempts were wrapping a value, not a function! I never tried to wrapp a function, frankly I do not know that it is thing in Swift or SwiftUI. So how can I make @ShapeBuilder works like @ViewBuilder works, I know that I must use Tuple or more correctly TupleShape, so I think I should define TupleShape as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First we should ask whether it's worth writing a `ShapeBuilder` instead of writing an `AnyShape` type like this:

```
public struct AnyShape: Shape {
    public let makePath: (CGRect) -> Path

    public init(makePath: @escaping (CGRect) -> Path) {
        self.makePath = makePath
    }

    public init<Wrapped: Shape>(_ shape: Wrapped) {
        self.makePath = { shape.path(in: $0) }
    }

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return makePath(rect)
    }
}
```

We can use `AnyShape` to write your `testForShape` function like this:

```
func testForShape(value: Bool) -> AnyShape {
    if value {
        return AnyShape(Circle())
    }
    else {
        return AnyShape(Rectangle())
    }
}
```

I've used `AnyShape` in various projects.

### UPDATE

Apple added an [`AnyShape`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyshape#) type to SwiftUI in the 2022 releases of iOS 16, macOS 13, etc. The Apple version doesn't have the `makePath` initializer like my implementation above does, but has [an equivalent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyshape/init(_:)) of the `Wrapped` initializer, which is sufficient to solve the problem stated in the question.

### NOW BACK TO THE ORIGINAL

Anyway, if we want to write `ShapeBuilder`, we can start with the simplest possible implementation, which only supports a body containing a single, unconditional child shape:

```
@resultBuilder
public struct ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock<C0: Shape>(_ c0: C0) -> C0 { c0 }
}
```

We can now use it like this:

```
@ShapeBuilder
func shape1() -> some Shape {
    Circle()
}
```

Hooray!

We can extend it to support a body containing **no** child shapes by adding a zero-argument `buildBlock` and an `EmptyShape` type for it to return:

```
extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock() -> EmptyShape { EmptyShape() }
}

public struct EmptyShape: Shape {
    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path { Path() }
}
```

Now we can write the following function without errors:

```
@ShapeBuilder
func shape0() -> some Shape {
}
```

To support an `if` statement without an `else` clause, we add a `buildOptional` method and an `OptionalShape` type for it to return:

```
extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildOptional<C0: Shape>(_ c0: C0?) -> OptionalShape<C0> {
        return OptionalShape(c0)
    }
}

public struct OptionalShape<Content: Shape>: Shape {
    public let content: Content?

    public init(_ content: Content?) {
        self.content = content
    }

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return content?.path(in: rect) ?? Path()
    }
}
```

Now we can use it like this:

```
@ShapeBuilder
func shape2(flag: Bool) -> some Shape {
    if flag {
        Circle()
    }
}
```

To support an `if` statement **with** an `else` clause, and to support a `switch` statement, we add `buildEither` and an `EitherShape` type for it to return:

```
extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildEither<First: Shape, Second: Shape>(first: First) -> EitherShape<First, Second> {
        return .first(first)
    }

    public static func buildEither<First: Shape, Second: Shape>(second: Second) -> EitherShape<First, Second> {
        return .second(second)
    }
}

public enum EitherShape<First: Shape, Second: Shape>: Shape {
    case first(First)
    case second(Second)

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        switch self {
        case .first(let first): return first.path(in: rect)
        case .second(let second): return second.path(in: rect)
        }
    }
}
```

We can now write this function:

```
@ShapeBuilder
func shape3(_ n: Int) -> some Shape {
    if n < 0 {
        Rectangle()
    } else {
        switch n {
        case 0:
            EmptyShape()
        case 1:
            Rectangle()
        default:
            Capsule()
        }
    }
}
```

We can support combining two child shapes by writing a `buildBlock` method that takes two arguments, and a `Tuple2Shape` for it to return:

```
extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock<C0: Shape, C1: Shape>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) -> Tuple2Shape<C0, C1> {
        return Tuple2Shape(c0, c1)
    }
}

public struct Tuple2Shape<C0: Shape, C1: Shape>: Shape {
    public let tuple: (C0, C1)

    public init(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) {
        tuple = (c0, c1)
    }

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = tuple.0.path(in: rect)
        path.addPath(tuple.1.path(in: rect))
        return path
    }
}
```

Now we can write this function:

```
@ShapeBuilder
func shape4() -> some Shape {
    Circle()
    Rectangle()
}
```

We can support combining two child shapes by writing a `buildBlock` method that takes three arguments, and a `Tuple3Shape` for it to return:

```
extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock<C0: Shape, C1: Shape, C2: Shape>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2) -> Tuple3Shape<C0, C1, C2> {
        return Tuple3Shape(c0, c1, c2)
    }
}

public struct Tuple3Shape<C0: Shape, C1: Shape, C2: Shape>: Shape {
    public let tuple: (C0, C1, C2)

    public init(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2) {
        tuple = (c0, c1, c2)
    }

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = tuple.0.path(in: rect)
        path.addPath(tuple.1.path(in: rect))
        path.addPath(tuple.2.path(in: rect))
        return path
    }
}
```

That lets us write this function:

```
@ShapeBuilder
func shape5() -> some Shape {
    Circle()
    Rectangle()
    Capsule()
}
```

`ViewBuilder` has `buildBlock` methods up to arity 10, but I'm not going to write out any more. You can do it yourself if you need them.

Anyway, here's the `ShapeBuilder` implementation all together for easy copy'n'paste:

```
@resultBuilder
public struct ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock<C0: Shape>(_ c0: C0) -> C0 { c0 }
}

extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock() -> EmptyShape { EmptyShape() }
}

public struct EmptyShape: Shape {
    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path { Path() }
}

extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildOptional<C0: Shape>(_ c0: C0?) -> OptionalShape<C0> {
        return OptionalShape(c0)
    }
}

public struct OptionalShape<Content: Shape>: Shape {
    public let content: Content?

    public init(_ content: Content?) {
        self.content = content
    }

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return content?.path(in: rect) ?? Path()
    }
}

extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildEither<First: Shape, Second: Shape>(first: First) -> EitherShape<First, Second> {
        return .first(first)
    }

    public static func buildEither<First: Shape, Second: Shape>(second: Second) -> EitherShape<First, Second> {
        return .second(second)
    }
}

public enum EitherShape<First: Shape, Second: Shape>: Shape {
    case first(First)
    case second(Second)

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        switch self {
        case .first(let first): return first.path(in: rect)
        case .second(let second): return second.path(in: rect)
        }
    }
}

extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock<C0: Shape, C1: Shape>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) -> Tuple2Shape<C0, C1> {
        return Tuple2Shape(c0, c1)
    }
}

public struct Tuple2Shape<C0: Shape, C1: Shape>: Shape {
    public let tuple: (C0, C1)

    public init(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) {
        tuple = (c0, c1)
    }

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = tuple.0.path(in: rect)
        path.addPath(tuple.1.path(in: rect))
        return path
    }
}

extension ShapeBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock<C0: Shape, C1: Shape, C2: Shape>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2) -> Tuple3Shape<C0, C1, C2> {
        return Tuple3Shape(c0, c1, c2)
    }
}

public struct Tuple3Shape<C0: Shape, C1: Shape, C2: Shape>: Shape {
    public let tuple: (C0, C1, C2)

    public init(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2) {
        tuple = (c0, c1, c2)
    }

    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = tuple.0.path(in: rect)
        path.addPath(tuple.1.path(in: rect))
        path.addPath(tuple.2.path(in: rect))
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the most advanced answer ever I seen in SOF! thanks, You did used very good naming about AnyShape, Asperi did help me also about AnyShape, but your naming and putting those together makes it perfect! I am missing the use case of a `for` or let we call `ForEachShape` I am looking make this work as well: `@ShapeBuilder func shapeTest() -> some Shape { for index in 0...20.indices { Circle().path(in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(index), y: CGFloat(index), width: 100.0, height: 100.0)) } }`

Comment: Try to write `ForEachShape` and `buildArray` yourself. If you have trouble, post a new question showing your attempt.

Comment: I code it in this way, could you say your opinion about it? Is it correct way or approach? I am not sure about it. If I should make it a question let me know please. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL9jt.jpg

Comment: Also I am working on VStack for Shape here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71088382/13899957 it is about to get closed! for unknown reason! :(